# AES-CBC Hash Function Collision Resistance

Tags: hash, aes, collision-resistance, cbc

I am using AES-CBC as a hash function which is encrypting a block of length n. The blocks, m = (m1, m2, ..., mn). The IV is one block long and the encryption key is length 128, 192 or 256 bits.

Will I get collisions? And if so, how could I find examples?

I expect to find collisions every 2^(n/2) hashes but I don't imagine this would allow me to find any matches in the next 10000000 years.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. What is the origin of this question? Why do you need to hash with PRP instead of a PRF? Consider that how many AES-CBC encryptions your machine can execute in one second then you can decide the necessary time on a single machine while omitting to build a hashTable to find the collision effectively.

Comment: Interestingly, if you only encrypt one block, what will you get?

Comment: With AES, the hash will be the ciphertext of the last message block. Will it be dependent on finding a hash every 2^(n/2) or every 2^(128|192|256)/2??

Comment: A block cipher is a family of permutations where a key selects one of the permutations. That is the real effect of the secret key!. So you have a fixed permutation.

Comment: Ah I see, as AES is an injective function I suppose there wouldn't be any collisions but this slide I found indicates otherwise. What is your interpretation?

Page 73. http://ce.sharif.edu/~b_momeni/ce441/15-crypto-sym.pdf

Comment: If you encrypt one block, there is no collision, however, after one block, you will have.

Comment: The collisions are between the last ciphertext blocks on two plaintext messages. I'm not sure I follow

Comment: Ty v much :) +20 social credits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using AES-CBC as a hash function which is encrypting a block of length n. The blocks, m = (m1, m2, ..., mn). The IV is one block long and the encryption key is length 128, 192 or 256 bits.

Questions:

- What is the key?  Is it fixed in advance, or is it something secret?  BTW: if it's 'something secret', you don't have a standard hash function (where the entire descryption is public; you may have a MAC, but see below).
- What is the hash output?  Is it the entire encrypted message, or is it just the last block.

Here are the possibilities:

- If the key is fixed in advance, and the hash is the entire encrypted message, then of course you will never have a collision (because you can decrypt and get the original message back - you couldn't do that if there were a collision).  Of course, a hash that is as long as the original message isn't very interesting.
- If the key is fixed in advance, and the hash is the last block, then it is easy to create collisions (and preimages) - all the attacker needs to do to generate a preimage is formulate the message (except for one block), insert the known start state (IV) and final state (the target hash), and work toward the middle - the necessary state of that one unspecified block can easily be found.
- If the key is unknown and the hash is the last block, this is actually the construction known as CBC-MAC.  For fixed length messages, it's a decent message authentication code - however, if the attacker can vary the message length, he can come up with forgeries and collisions.